# java.awt.Point and java.awt.Rectangle in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I thought I might give JAXB a try to take care of storing and restoring settings. But I ran into trouble even with the "simplest" example:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Config {
  public Point myPoint = new Point();
}
```

And from somewhere else in the code I tried:

```
JAXB.marshal(new Config(), new File("config.xml"));
```

This produces some exception with a very long stack trace...

Does that mean, i need to write a wrapper class for x,y before I can use JAXB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object(s) to be marshalled must be annotated as JAXB object(s) indeed. Depending on the JAXB implementation, this can also be achieved by external mapping files like in the case of [MOXy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141543/can-moxy-serialize-pojo-with-getters-only-without-need-to-explicitly-put-annotat).

You don't have to write a wrapper class, you can just add the required annotations like `@XmlRootElement` to your existing classes. However, in the case of classes you don't have control over (like `java.awt.Point`), you would use an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, an example of which can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm).