# Jersey/JAXB hates Rectangle

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I have a Java application which uses Jersey for REST services. I have several REST endpoints, all of which return valid JSON (the desired format). We have a new endpoint, a GET, that returns valid JSON, except for one element, a Java Rectangle. This is the response we get:

```
[
    {
        "customers": {
            "current": 2,
            "max": 16
        },
        "format": "ABCD",
        "dataPoints": 20,
        "window": "java.awt.Rectangle[x=50,y=50,width=400,height=300]"
    }
]
```

As you can see, that Rectangle is not valid JSON. I've tried several things, but none worked. The things I've tried include adding `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlElement` and `@XmlAttribute` on the Rectangle element on the class. The only thing that does is move to the malformed JSON to the top of the output.

I suspect it doesn't work because the Rectangle class doesn't have `@XmlRootElement` in its class declaration, therefore JAXB can't properly convert it into XML (and then into JSON). If this is the case, do I need to inherit from Rectangle just to include that annotation? It seems like the JAXB developers would've accounted for built-in types. Is my assumption correct, or is there another solution?

Comment: You need to make an `XmlAdapter` for `java.awt.Rectangle`. See [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm#TLJAX424).

Comment: Related to [java.awt.Point and java.awt.Rectangle in JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070513/java-awt-point-and-java-awt-rectangle-in-jaxb)

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasFritsch. I copied the example precisely and now `window` displays as an empty array. That's wrong, but I really have no idea how to debug this error.

Comment: I needed to add all the setters to the stand-in class (the article didn't mention those). After adding them, everything worked perfectly! @ThomasFritsch, if you turn your first response into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm#TLJAX424) you can solve the problem like this.

JAXB is out-of-the-box not able to marshall/unmarshall `java.awt.Rectangle`.

Because we cannot change the `Rectangle` class, we will write a new class, `MyRectangle` which JAXB knows how to marshall/unmarshall.

```
public class MyRectangle {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public MyRectangle() {
    }

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Then we need an [XmlAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html)
for converting between `Rectangle` and `MyRectangle`:

```
public class RectangleXmlAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MyRectangle, Rectangle> {

    @Override
    public Rectangle unmarshal(MyRectangle v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        return new Rectangle(v.getX(), v.getY(), v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public MyRectangle marshal(Rectangle v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        return new MyRectangle(v.x, v.y, v.width, v.height);
    }
}
```

Finally, you use the [`@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html)
annotation to tell JAXB to use our `RectangleXmlAdapter` when marshalling/unmarshalling
`Rectangle` properties. For example:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RectangleXmlAdapter.class)
private Rectangle window;
```

Then this `window` property will have an XML representation like this:

```
<window>
    <x>50</x>
    <y>50</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
</window>
```

and then (by some Jersey-magic) a JSON representation like this:

```
"window": {
    "x": 50,
    "y": 50,
    "width": 400,
    "height": 300
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already followed the article to get this stuff working, but thanks for the in-depth answer! I'd like to note that once JAXB can convert the class into XML, it can quickly convert it into JSON, which is what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: I've updated my answer according to your note about XML-JSON-conversion.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution might be to do the JSON conversion yourself and then return the JSON string as the entity of the Response, as shown below.

```
@Path("/rectangle")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@GET
public Response getRect() {

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonRect = gson.toJson(r);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(jsonRect).build();
}
```

therefore not using JAXB at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't work. My REST endpoint calls another class which has the data it needs to return. Using your suggestion, the getRect() never gets called (perhaps because it's returning a string and not a Rectangle?). Thanks anyway.